# vb.net exception OleDB with database ACCESS

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

If only have these code

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class Form1
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;data source=C:\Users\cesar\Escritorio\centroeducativo.mdb")
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
        Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            con.Open()
            con.Close()

        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why show error

```
Excepción del tipo 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' en System.Data.dll
Excepción del tipo 'System.InvalidOperationException' en System.Data.dll
```

I have already connection to source data

[image]

I have nothing unusual, I'm confused

Comment: I'm confused, too. You are suppressing the Exception so it's not clear how your code can "show [an] error". The error message you offer is also incomplete. You could try putting `MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)` inside the `Catch` block to see if you get some more meaningful information to work with.

Comment: I would guess this is being seen in the Immediate Window as form_load would display an exception there. Following Gord Thompson's advice would give you a more detailed error message. I would have to assume for no more than you have that you have a path or misspelling in the path/filename combination or the filename is not at that location.

Comment: In the end I went back to redo it could not lose more time. Followed another tutorial. Thanks for helpme